# How can I enable unit templates?

Tags: systemd

I have written a my own unit template:

```
/etc/systemd/user/my_service@.service
```

This is the base for a bunch of services I want to come up at boot. I do want to create each service as a symlink to the template something like this:

```
$ cd /etc/systemd/user
$ sudo ln -s my_service@.service my_service@runner001.service
$ sudo ln -s my_service@.service my_service@runner002.service
...
```

But if I now try to enable the services I get:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable my_service@runner001.service
Failed to execute operation: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

To solve this I copied the file instead:

```
$ cd /etc/systemd/user
$ sudo cp my_service@.service my_service@runner001.service
$ sudo cp my_service@.service my_service@runner002.service
...
```

Now `systemctl enable` works as expected.

**But:** Making all those copies and keeping them synced when the template is changed are awkward and sort of defeats the purpose of a templating system I think.

What am I missing here? Could the *runners* be enabled without copying the template?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and systemd=229

---

**Btw**: If I after enabling of the service replace it with a symlink it will still work for some `systemctl` commands (`daemon-reload`, `start`, `stop` and `status`) while `is-enabled`, `enable` and `disable` will all fail with:

```
Failed to execute operation: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Strange I think, and I have not tried to reboot my system to see if that works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need symlinks. Just use

`systemctl start/enable my_service@runner001.service`. Then, systemd will use your template directly.

See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers for more info about specifiers (ie, variables you can use inside you template)

If you want more, paste template and expected result.

Comment: The template must **not** be placed in `users`. When I moved it to `/etc/systemd/system` it worked instantly!